# script won't run a section of code

Tags: autohotkey

I have this small script that is supposed to open up an app and type in some letters. However, for some reason the script won't run a section of code. It gets up to winMaximize and then stops. But if the app is already open then the section DOES run?? Not sure if I'm doing anything wrong, ideas?

```
#NoEnv
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#WinActivateForce
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1

;if 0 < 2  ; The left side of a non-expression if-statement is always the name of a variable.
;{
;   MsgBox, This script requires 2 incoming parameters but it only received %0%.
;    ExitApp
;}
IfWinNotExist, ahk_exe photoscan.exe
{
    RunWait, "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\photoscan.exe"
}
WinActivate  ; Automatically uses the window found above.
sleep,5
WinMaximize
;Macro5:
Click, 499, 426, 0
Click, 497, 427, 0
Click, 496, 427, 0
Click, 493, 428, 0
Click, 492, 429, 0
Click, 487, 431, 0
Click, 485, 433, 0
Click, 482, 435, 0
Click, 481, 435, 0
Click, 480, 435, 0
Click, 479, 436, 0
Click, 478, 436, 0
Click, 477, 437, 0
Click, 477, 438, 0
Click, 476, 438, 0
Send, {LControl Down}
Send, {r}
Click, -56, 157, 0
WinActivate, Run Python Script ahk_class QWidget
Send, {LControl Up}
Send, {LControl Down}
Send, {LControl Up}
Send, {LControl Down}
Send, {a}
Send, {LControl Up}
Send, {Backspace}
Send, {%1%} ; 1st argument is the images folder directory
Send, {Tab}
Send, {Tab}
Send, {LControl Down}
Send, {%2%} ; 2nd argument is additional args (in our case, the projectName)
Send, {LControl Up}
Send, {Backspace}
Send, {b}
Sleep, 703
Send, {Enter}
Click, 476, 438, 0
Return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By ommitting any `wintitle` parameters, you are calling `winactivate` and `winmaximize` on the ["The Last Found Window"](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#LastFoundWindow). I think winMaximize simply doesn't execute because there was just no found window (it is called "the last found window", and not "the window which was found last, or maybe it wasn't").

Afaican see, your stack trace is

```
> 
> IfWinNotExist, ahk_exe photoscan.exe ; does not exist. -> last found window: NONE
> RunWait, "C:\Program Files\Agisoft\PhotoScan Pro\photoscan.exe"
> ; still: last found window: NONE
> WinActivate / WinMaximize ; called on NONE
```

Not sure why `winActivate` terminates though. Either way, if you add `ahk_exe photoscan.exe` to winactivate and winmaximize, you should be fine